# How to get a Run Script phase to run first during compile in xcode?

Tags: xcode, compilation, plist

In xcode 10.2, there is a run-script build phase. I have a script to copy a framework to a specific pod in `DerivedData/somename-someguid/products/etc`...

However, it seems that the script is not running first based on the print statements and it fails to find the file. If I manually copy the file there first, I can see the output of my script in the build log and it succeeds.

I tried dragging it up in the build-phase panel. I also tried adding it to the copy-file section, but copy does not understand how to embed with the correct pod.

Is there a way to specify the order of running these scripts? Is there a pre-everything section I don't know about?

Answer (score 0):

Of course, it turns out I had the `run script` phase on the main app project instead of the pod project targets not realizing it built the pods first. So adding it there fixes it. Saving other noobs from this mistake by leaving the question up....